# Are Cloudant indexes presisted?

Tags: cloudant

On what condition are Cloudant indexes deleted?  I created five indexes via the web console on Monday and today I notice that only the default index on _id still remains.

I did delete all the records in the database earlier this week but not any of the indices.  Are the indices deleted when the database contains no documents?

Comment: Indexes are stored as design documents. After you create an index you will see the design document listed under "All Documents" with an id similar to this: `_design/72f7db328b2fd22612e9f7fdbb4031bea5b11546`. It sounds like you may have deleted that document when you purged your database - which would delete the index.

Comment: Yes, when I went back to all the design docs I had created they were gone.  I deleted JSON docs in the web UI by selecting all docs on a page and deleting them.  I don't think I explicitly deleted design docs but perhaps they are deleted when all documents are removed.

Comment: Design docs are also listed under "All Documents". So, if you selected all then you would have deleted the design documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudant indexes are stored in design documents. Design documents are like regular documents but their id is prefixed with `_design/` with it's contents providing meaning to the database setting up views, query indexes etc. The important bit to note is that the design document is a regular document, so it's included in list for all documents in the dashboard. When you deleted the all the documents in the Dashboard, you also deleted the design documents.

Comment: Is there a simple way to delete all non-design documents without going page by page and selecting all the docs on a page?  This is when I miss the command line ;-)